# Add word hints in WordPress post editor

Tags: visual-editor

Is there a way to add list of word hints e.g. in popup in post editor. Something like spell-checker that highlights some text and allow to choose alternative.

Comment: Is this aimed at the pre-5.0 editor or the post 5.0 editor? ( Gutenberg )

Comment: Preferably pre-5.0 editor, as long as Gutenberg is not default WordPress editor. But solutions for both are welcome.

Comment: The answer is yes. If you want to implement such a thing you should ask about smaller well defined "units of work". As it is right now the question is so broad an answer is unlikely to fit the format here, or will be too vague to be useful.